# Brake tags removed on x-ray scrape

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, x-ray

I am new to JS. I am scraping a url with X-ray. The tags are removed when scraped as expected, but I want the `<br>` tag to be replaced with something like `;`

For example:
If I scrape something like `'span#scraped-portion'`

```
<span id="scraped-portion"><span class="bold>NodeJS</span><br>
    <span class="bold>Version:</span> 8<br><span class="bold>Date released:</span> 2017 Jan<br><span class="bold>Description:</span>Some other text
</span>
```

I will get result similar to the following

```
NodeJS /n Version: 8Date released: 2017 JanDescription: Some other text
```

The text around `<br>` tags get added together and it will get difficult to understand what is what.
So I want the `<br>` tag to be replaced replaced with something like `;`.

Is it possible or Should I better use other libraries?

Comment: perhaps a [filter](https://github.com/matthewmueller/x-ray#filters) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **UPDATE**

I found a pure X-Ray based solution without the need of replacing `<br>` tags  in html prior utilizing X-Ray (see original solution below).

That way you're going to use X-Ray's `filter` functions in addition with embedding X-Ray functions in each other (sort of nesting).

Firstly we're going to replace `<br>` tags in original html by using custom filter function (called `replaceLineBreak`) defined for X-Ray.
Secondly we're going to use the result of replace with rebuilding the original html structure (by re-adding `<span id="scraped-portion">`) as the first argument of an X-Ray call.

Hope you'll like it!

```
    var x = Xray({
    filters: {
        replaceLineBreak: function (value) { return value.replace(/\<br\>/g, ';'); },
    }
});
var html =
`
    <span id="scraped-portion"><span class="bold">NodeJS</span><br>
        <span class="bold">Version:</span> 8<br><span class="bold">Date released:</span> 2017 Jan<br><span class="bold">Description:</span>Some other text
    </span>
`;

x(html,
    '#scraped-portion@html | replaceLineBreak' /// Filter function called to replace '<br>' to ';'
)(function (err, obj) {
    x(`<span id="scraped-portion">${obj}</span>`, /// Restore oroginal html structure to have the outer span with id 'scraped-portion
        '#scraped-portion'
    )(function (err2, obj2) { res.header("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"); res.write(obj2); res.end(); })
    });
```

Resulting the following string:

```
NodeJS;   Version: 8;Date released: 2017 Jan;Description:Some other text
```

---

> ORIGINAL SOLUTION

why not replacing all occurences of `<br>` tags prior to processing the html code by X-Ray?

```
function tst(req, res) {
var x = Xray();
var html =
`
    <span id="scraped-portion"><span class="bold">NodeJS</span><br>
        <span class="bold">Version:</span> 8<br><span class="bold">Date released:</span> 2017 Jan<br><span class="bold">Description:</span>Some other text
    </span>
`.replace(/\<br\>/g, ';');

x
    (
    html,
    ['span#scraped-portion']
    )(function (err, obj) { res.header("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"); res.write(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)); res.end(); })
    ;
}
```

Then your code would result something like this

`NodeJS;\n      Version: 8;Date released: 2017 Jan;Description:Some other text\n`

which pretty much seems to meet your requirements

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll test it soon. Now I have one more question. How can I create `[{"Version": "8", "Date released": "2017 Jan", "Description" : "Some other text"}]` . I ll create a new question for this soon too